# Intercept ActionBar touch events

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to disable the touch events on the android ActionBar programatically and I can't find a way to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ever figure anything out on this?

Comment: @mattblang unfortunately no. I created a boolean and I use it onOptionsItemSelected or other methods that are triggerd by a click on the actionbar